# Hide div which has double ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, ng-hide

I have this markup:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="value2 in requirements | orderBy:'ControlGroupIdentifier'">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div ng-repeat="controlgroup in value2.ControlGroup"
             ng-show="controlgroup.ListOfControls.length > 0">
            <table ng-if="controlgroup.ListOfControls.length > 0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="value in controlgroup.ListOfControls = (controlgroup.ListOfControls  | filter: searchCompanyControl )">
                      &nbsp;
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is hide the first div which has the ng-repeat for requirements if all control groups are hidden based on

> controlgroup.ListOfControls.length > 0

I'm able to hide the second div ng-repeat but I'm not sure how to hide the most outer ng-repeat if all the control groups in the requirement are hidden based on the condition that there are no list of controls.

Comment: You need to add code in your controller to check if some() (hint hint) requirement has a non-empty control group.

Comment: if you have some example pls let me know thx

Comment: `let nonEmptyRequirementPresent = requirements.some(r => r.ControlGroup.length > 0);`

Comment: The `ng-repeat` in the `<tr>` element looks sketchy.

Answer (score -1):

You could use "ng-if" on the top div.

```
<div class="row" ng-if="controlgroup.ListOfControls.length > 0" ng-repeat="value2 in requirements | orderBy:'ControlGroupIdentifier'">
```

I am not sure if this would cancel your ng-repeat or not, but if it does, you could wrap it in its own div.

eg.

```
<div ng-if="controlgroup.ListOfControls.length > 0">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="value2 in requirements | orderBy:'ControlGroupIdentifier'">
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: I think the control group is declared in the inner scope and will not work above, but let me try

Comment: You are right, controlgroup would be referring go the value2 itself. Hmm...

Comment: You might be better suited filtering before your repeat. Here's the idea https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/16679c7. Please comment if you find a more efficient (in-dom) way of doing it! I am dealing with something similar.